# python run function schedule at specific time with thread

Tags: python, datetime, time, scheduled-tasks, datetime-format

I'm trying to run function at specific time in python using schedule
I tried

```
    self.check_run = False
    ...
    def job(self,x):
            print("I'm working... {}".format(x))
            self.check_run = True
    schedule.every().day.at(str(self.mytime)).do(lambda: self.job(count))
    while 1:
           schedule.run_pending()
           time.sleep(1)
           if self.check_run:
                self.check_run = False
                break
```

this code working fine, but I need to run another function before `self.mytime` in several minutes and another function after `self.mytime` in several minutes also.

so how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have overridden the threading. `Timer` class to gain access to the timer functions so I can execute my code before and after the desired `timered` function is executed. A small example so you can get a lead what to do:

```
class MyTimer(threading.Timer):
    def run(self):
        self.finished.wait(self.interval)
        # Here is what will happen BEFORE your code will be executed
        if not self.finished.is_set():
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.finished.set()
        # Here is what will happen AFTER your code was executed.
```

Will be glad to help more or explain my self better if needed.